# Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module when using Web Worker in React Vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm using React with Typescript and Vite for my project. I've implemented Web Worker, here is the code

```
const workercode = () => {
    self.onmessage = async function (e) {   
        const { chanel, importMode, image, token } = e.data;
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("chanel", chanel);
        formData.append("import_mode", importMode);
        formData.append(
            "files",
            new Blob(image, {
                type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            })
        );
        console.log("Message received from main script");
        const response = await fetch(import.meta.env.BASE_URL, {
            method: "post",
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        // const workerResult = "Received from main: " + e.data;
        console.log("Posting message back to main script");
        // self.postMessage(api.message()); // eslint-disable-line no-restricted-globals
        self.postMessage(data); // eslint-disable-line no-restricted-globals
    };
};

let code = workercode.toString();
code = code.substring(code.indexOf("{") + 1, code.lastIndexOf("}"));

const blob = new Blob([code], { type: "application/javascript" });
const WorkerScript = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
export default WorkerScript;
```

I've worked around several instructions but none of them work. Any answer is appreciated

Comment: What's your Vite config look like? Can't really help until we see that.